# Long live HTTP connections using Tire gem

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I am doing bulk indexing using Tire Gem as the client for Elasticsearch

```
index = Tire::Index.new('oldskool')
index.bulk_store(bulk_values)
```

I monitor the HTTP connections on my Elasticsearch cluster by using the http monitor API,

`￼￼￼￼curl 'localhost:9200/_nodes/http/stats'`

In the JSON response that I get ,

`..."http":{"current_open" : 10, "total_opened" : 18345}`

I observed that the "total_opened" field value goes on increasing rapidly. I think this means that the Tire gem is not using persistent connections while bulk indexing( Please correct me if I am wrong ).

How can I use Tire Gem to make persistent connections with Elasticsearch while doing bulk indexing?

Comment: Elasticsearch is RESTful. Every request is serviced in isolation, and can be services solely on the content of the request... I might be wrong, but  I thought that meant that you wouldn't need to keep a connection open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Tire` uses `RestClient` which doesn't support `keep-alive`. You can switch to [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) client by configuring `Tire` for example like this.

```
require 'tire/http/clients/curb'
Tire.configure do
  client Tire::HTTP::Client::Curb
end
```